# Как найти строку начиная с заданного индекса regex

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

```
str = " нужно1 Много текста и нужно2 Много текста"
```

Есть фильтр

```
filter = " (.+) Много текста"
```

Чтобы найти подстроки по фильтру filter нужно прописать комманду

```
text = re.search(filter,str)
```

Теперь в переменной text, будет такое значение

```
" нужно1 Много текста"
```

Но хотелось бы, найти подстроку с заданного индекса, что-то наподобии этого

```
index = 20
text = re.search(filter,str,index)
```

В переменной text теперь значение:

```
" нужно2 Много текста"
```

Как используя regex, можно задать индекс, с которого будет начинаться поиск?

Comment: Ничего непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью костыля

```
str = " нужно1 Много текста и нужно2 Много текста"
filter = " (.+) Много текста"
index = 50
str2 = str[50:]
text = re.search(filter,str2)
print(text)
```

Но костыли не особо хотелось использовать, я думал есть способ поиска с заданного индекса через regexp, стал спрашивать в интернете на что получил плевок в душу.